Is it advisable to use PLSR components in another linear equation?
I currently possess biological data from two groups (healthy vs disease) in the form of protein concentrations and I was interested in determining what the relationship was between these protein concentrations within group with respect to age (timepoint). To reiterate, my covariates were my protein concentrations (of [n x m] dimension), and my response variable was age ([n x 1] dimension) where I have n subjects for both groups healthy and disease. I ran a PLSR within group (disease only or healthy only) to determine how well the protein concentrations (after being standardized) were able to predict aging.
I also possess another dataset that holds fMRI data and aging for the same two groups. I am interested in determining how well these protein signatures explain the related fMRI results. I was curious if I could run a linear model for each group. The formula would follow the following strucure: $fMRI_{healthy} = PLSR_{{component1}_{scores}} + PLSR_{{component2}_{scores}} + \epsilon_{healthy}$
The reason why I would like to use the scores is because it allows me to interrogate each individual subjects protein signature in determining how well it can explain the same subject's fMRI data. The concern I have though is that the PLSR models are a predictive model that maximizes the covariation between the covariates and the response. That response is present in the fMRI data as the fMRI data was collected at each respective timepoint as well. So I am not sure how valid the above mentioned is and I was wondering if someone could help clarify if this a valid analytical procedure.
